# Efficient way to compare strings and get unique value

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, string-comparison

I have comma separated n numbers of stings contain numbers like `1,2,3,4,5,6` etc and their length can be `n`. I have to find numbers those are occurring in all string.

Example input:

```
$str1       = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
$str2       = '0,1,4,5,6,7,10,20,23,34,333,78';
$str3       = '5,4,8,3,1,1,1,5,6';
```

expected output:

```
$result     = '1,4,5,6';
```

I know I can do this by comparing each string but its not that much efficient.
Second option is to get shortest string, then check numbers of that string against each string. It will be little efficient then previous one.

All I want to is to get much efficient method to this.

**EDIT:**

My html where I get the values from:

```
<form name="cstm_data_form" id="cstm_data_form">
    <div id="dataSet0" onclick="removeCandidate(0)">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ward_name[0]" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,50,52,53,54,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66">   
    </div>
    <div id="dataSet1" onclick="removeCandidate(1)">

        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ward_name[1]" value="4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,64,65,66">

    </div>
    <div id="dataSet2" onclick="removeCandidate(2)">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ward_name[2]" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66">

    </div>
    <div id="dataSet3" onclick="removeCandidate(3)">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ward_name[3]" value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35">

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks like homework from where I'm standing. Not that there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: Show your current code and where you are stuck.

Comment: [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv)+[`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) pretty much already covers that.

Comment: @Andrew Its not home work or assignment. Its real life problem. I have updated question. Please have a look.

Comment: Now I get confused. What has your question to do with this html?!

Comment: @mario thanks for array_intersects. I guess it will work.

Comment: @Andrew strings I mentioned are coming from this form :-) actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$result = array_unique(array_intersect(explode(',', $str1), explode(',', $str2), explode(',', $str3)));
```

Edit: Well the point is to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) strings to arrays, then get [intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and finally pick [unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) values.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all of your variables which you have, [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them by a comma and put the exploded array into `$arr`.

After this just call [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), which will call the function in this way: `array_intersect($arr[0], $arr[1], ...)`.

And at the end just take all unique values from the array with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
<?php

    $str1       = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
    $str2       = '0,1,4,5,6,7,10,20,23,34,333,78';
    $str3       = '5,4,8,3,1,1,1,5,6';

    $i = 1;
    while(isset(${"str" . $i})) {
        $arr[] = explode(",", ${"str" . $i});
        $i++;
    }

    $result = array_unique(call_user_func_array("array_intersect", $arr));
    print_r($result);  //As a string: echo implode(",", $result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = array("1","2",...);
$str2 = ...;
$str3 = ...;

$result = array_intersect($str1,$str2,$str3);
```

That should works. If you want a `,` do a `explode()` like the others show to you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string into array , then [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) will return common values.

```
$arr1       = explode(',','1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');
$arr2       = explode(',','0,1,4,5,6,7,10,20,23,34,333,78');
$arr3       = explode(',','5,4,8,3,1,1,1,5,6');
$arrayInterset = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);

echo '<pre>';print_r($arrayInterset);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For something in the context of your html form, as a loop through your values:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['hidden_ward_name'] as $key=>$string) {
        if($key == 0) {
                $result = array_unique(explode(',', $string));
        } else {
                $result = array_intersect(array_unique(explode(',', $string)), $result);
        }
}

print_r(array_sort($result));
```